# Get Value of dropdowns with same name using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have some dropdowns shown in my asp.net mvc application with the same name (say: 5 dropdowns with the same name 'uniquedropdown'.)

I need to get all the selected values of the dropdowns with the same name using jquery.

How to get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `$('select[name="uniquedropdown"]').val()` as that will return only the value of the first `<select>` in the page.

To get an an array of values

```
var values = $.map($('select[name="uniquedropdown"]'), function (e) {
                 return $('option:selected', e).val();
             });
```

or

```
var values = $.map($('select[name="uniquedropdown"]'), function (e) {
                 return $(e).val();
             });
```

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/avayi)**. add **/edit** to the URL to see the code

Answer (score 0):

Use the each function to iterate over them and push the values into an array.

```
 var selected = [];
 $('#uniquedropdown').each( function() {
     selected.push( $(this).val() );
 });
```

Comment: This will not work. `#` works for `id`, not names, and gives only the first match.